# Issues with spring cloud cli [NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand]

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have spring boot of version

```
Spring CLI v2.1.0.RELEASE
```

And installed spring cloud  of version

```
spring install org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cli:2.0.0.RELEASE
```

It got installed properly, but not able to do any cloud cli commands, I'm running in to below exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler.option(Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljoptsimple/OptionSpecBuilder;
>       at org.springframework.cloud.launcher.cli.LauncherCommand$LauncherOptionHandler.options(LauncherCommand.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.getParser(OptionHandler.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.options.OptionHandler.getHelp(OptionHandler.java:99)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.OptionParsingCommand.getHelp(OptionParsingCommand.java:44)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.core.HelpCommand.run(HelpCommand.java:105)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.run(CommandRunner.java:219)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.command.CommandRunner.runAndHandleErrors(CommandRunner.java:171)
>       at org.springframework.boot.cli.SpringCli.main(SpringCli.java:63)
>       ... 8 more

Can any one help me to find out right/working version to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by using proper versions
Spring CLI v2.0.0.RELEASE
And Spring Cloud CLI v2.0.0.RELEASE

Comment: Today (May 2022) I also ran into this. I fixed it: I installed Spring CLI 2.6.7 and Spring Cloud CLI 2.2.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue. After 2 days investigation, I found it is a version issue. Please use spring-boot-cli-1.5.13.BUILD-20180509.054058-23-bin, the issue will be solved.